# Laravel how to throw single error while form field is incorrectly filled

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

Normally when I create a form, errors are showing under the field where the data input was wrong. [image]

and the code looks like this

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Imie</label>
                    <div class="col-md6">
                        <input id="name" maxlength="255" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required autofocus>
                        @if ($errors->has('name'))
                            <span class='help-block'>
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have a specification from my client to not tell user which field is incorrectly  filled, and I have question how to make it look like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to delete all the error messages from sinle inputs and make only one on top like this:

```
@if (!empty($errors))
    <span class='help-block'>
        <strong>{{ "Some input field is not properly filled" }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

and all the input fields should be something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Imie</label>
    <div class="col-md6">
        <input id="name" maxlength="255" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required autofocus>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now if you have an error in any field you will get that message on top.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the *if* statement displaying the error located right below your `<input>` elements, then above your form, where you want to display the message, use the snippet below:

```
@if ($errors)
    <span class='help-block'>
        <strong>Wrong field form</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Here, we display *Wrong field form* to the user for any error that may occur after a submission attempt following the filling of the form.